# Clear all input fields on submit using Hyperscript

Tags: htmx, hyperscript

I'm playing around with htmx and hyperscript, and I want all input fields in the form below to be cleared on submit:

```html
<form hx-post="/example" hx-target="#table tbody" hx-swap="beforeend"
      _="<what should I write here??>">
        <label class="control-label" for="firstNameInput">First Name</label>
        <input id="firstNameInput" name="firstName" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="John"/>
        
        <label class="control-label" for="lastNameInput">Last Name</label>
        <input id="lastNameInput" name="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Doe"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried replacing `<what should I write here??>` with e.g. `on submit put '' into <input/>` and `on submit put '' into <input[value]/>` and lots of other combinations but I fail to get this work.

Q: How can I clear all input fields when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with `on htmx:afterRequest reset() me`

Comment: This works! But would you mind explaining why? :) Is "reset()" a method on form?

Comment: Yes, `reset` is documented here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Answer (score 0):

If you simply changing input directly, you do not need form or a reset input you can do it with `on:htmx:<event> set my value to ''`

```
<input 
   name="text" 
   hx-get="/processInput"
   hx-trigger="keyup[keyCode==13], text"
   hx-target=".output"
   _="on htmx:afterRequest set my value to ''">
</input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need hyperscript, htmx is enough.

**hx-on::after-request="this.reset()"**

This way you can reset the form after submitting it.

Example for Django (Python):

```
<form hx-post="{% url 'comment_add' post.id %}"
    hx-target="#tab-contents"
    hx-swap="afterbegin"
    hx-on::after-request="this.reset()">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```