# Proper way to clear the input field after form submission with HTMX

Tags: htmx

I have the following htmx component,

```html
<form hx-trigger="submit" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-post="/add" hx-target="#list">
    <input type="text" name="todo"/>
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

I want to clear the input field once the post request return a 201 response.

I was able to do it using following JS code,

```html
<script>
    htmx.on("htmx:afterRequest", (event) => {
       // By assuming the `el` is always the input element and the response is always 201 for testing.
       const el = event.detail.requestConfig.elt[0]
       el.value = '';
    })
</script>
```

Is there any other (better) way to do this ? Perhaps without writing any JS ?

Comment: in your 201 response, along with whatever your `list` element response is, also send back `<input type="text" name="todo"  hx-swap-oob="true" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're few ways to handle it:

1. Using [hx-swap-oob](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/), as mentioned by @pthomson, to either replace the whole form or the input only.
2. Using [hx-on::after-request](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-on/) attached to input element. This is pretty much an inline version of your solution.
3. Using [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org/) (htmx sister-lib): attach `_="on htmx:afterSend set my value to ''"` to the input element (pseudo-code)

My preference would be to use pt 1) and re-render the html content, just like you would do it without any htmx/js, but it all depends on your specific use case. Maybe inline scripting is good enough for this simple case.

Comment: With hyperscript is more simple, append to form this attribute `_="on htmx:afterRequest reset() me"`, reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200529/955594)